# Solve PDE using eigenfunction expansion and solve Green's Function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenfunctions, greens-function, sturm-liouville

The question is as follows: solve using the method of eigenfunction expansion
$$c\rho \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\left(K_0\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \right) + Q(x,t)$$
With boundary condition $u(0, t)=u(L,t)=0$ and initial condition $u(x, 0)=g(x)$

Additionally, $c, \rho, K_0$ are all functions of $x$

For eigenfunction expansion, we use $ u(x, t) = \sum{a_n(t)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)}$, so I substituted that into the partial equation, getting

$$ c \rho \frac{\partial a_n}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(K_0 a_n(t) \frac{n \pi}{L}\cos\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right) + Q(x, t)$$

Then I tried multiplying both sides by $\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right) $ and integrating from $0$ to $L$

$$ \frac{2}{L} \frac{\partial a_n}{\partial t}  \int c \rho \sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)  dx =
-a_n(t)  \left(\frac{n \pi}{L}\right)^2 \frac{2}{L} \int(K_0)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)  dx +
a_n(t) \frac{n\pi}{L} \frac{2}{L}  \int \cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L} \right)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right) \frac{\partial K_0}{\partial x}dx +
\frac{2}{L} \int Q(x, t)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)dx $$

I then swapped the $\sin^2$ for $(1-\cos)/2$, and the $\sin\cos$ for $\sin2$, and tried integrating by parts for both of those terms once, and did not get anywhere.

This is starting to look very complicated, and I'm wondering

1. Is this the correct approach? and
2. If this is the correct approach, is there some way of solving these integrals very easily?
3. How do I then go about finding a Green's function for this?

Comment: One question, why would you assume that each eigenfunction satisfies the pde?

Comment: I don't know if this would be related, but the question also says to assume that eigenfunctions of the pde are known

Comment: A different approach could possibly involve using the Sturm-Lioville equation, but I did not consider that in my initial work.